# CodeIgniter - resizing images causes "out of memory"

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-resizing

I wrote a utility (w/CodeIgniter 3.0.5) for a client that allows him to upload photos, and they're resized for the web. The script has been working fine for several months, but all of a sudden he's getting out-of-memory errors, along the lines of this:

---

*FILE NAME: IMG_0047.JPG test

Resizing image...

New image: /homepages/20/d153810528/htdocs/toolbox/stuff/images/tool_photos/IMG_0047_resized.JPG

New filename: IMG_0047_resized.JPG*

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 35389440) (tried to allocate
>   4032 bytes) in
>   /homepages/20/d153810528/htdocs/toolbox/cat/libraries/Image_lib.php on
>   line 1455

---

---

The "resized" images aren't actually saved.

I know the first choice solution is to allocate more memory with php_ini, but it appears that the hosting provider -- 1and1 . com -- doesn't allow that; it's set at a hard 120M; I'm guessing they don't want customers screwing with their shared servers.

Any thoughts?

Here's the code that handles the resizing:

```
   public function uploadapicture() {

$status = '';
$msg = '';
$file_element_name = 'picture';

if ($status !== 'error') {
    $config['upload_path'] = 'stuff/images/tool_photos/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 50;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)) {
        $status = 'error';
        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('','');
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $image_path = $data['full_path'];
        if (file_exists($image_path)) {
            $status = 'success';
            $msg = 'Main picture "' . $_FILES[$file_element_name]['name'] . '" successfully uploaded';
        } else {
            $status = 'error';
            $msg = 'There was a problem saving the main picture.';
        }
    }
    @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);

    $file_element_name = 'thumbnail';
    if ((strlen($_FILES[$file_element_name]['name']) > 0) && !$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name)) {
        $status = 'error';
        $msg .= $this->upload->display_errors('','');
    } else if (strlen($_FILES[$file_element_name]['name']) > 0) {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $image_path = $data['full_path'];
        if (file_exists($image_path)) {
            $status = 'success';
            $msg .= 'Thumbnail successfully uploaded';
        } else {
            $status = 'error';
            $msg .= 'There was a problem saving the thumbnail.';
        }
    }
    if ($status === 'success') {
        echo "<br><pre>Post stuff:" . print_r($_POST,1);
        $toolToInsert = array(
            'picture_filename' => $_FILES['picture']['name'],
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'purchase_price' => $this->input->post('purchase_price'),
            'public_notes' => $this->input->post('public_notes'),
            'public_misc' => $this->input->post('public_misc'),
            'purchased_from' => $this->input->post('purchased_from'),
            'private_purchase_date' => $this->input->post('private_purchase_date'),
            'private_purchase_price' => $this->input->post('private_purchase_price'),
            'purchase_location' => $this->input->post('purchase_location'),
            'sold_by' => $this->input->post('sold_by'),
            'date_sold' => $this->input->post('date_sold'),
            'sale_price' => $this->input->post('sale_price'),
            'sold_to_name' => $this->input->post('sold_to_name'),
            'sold_to_phone' => $this->input->post('sold_to_phone'),
            'sold_to_email' => $this->input->post('sold_to_email'),
            'private_notes' => $this->input->post('private_notes'),
            'private_misc' => $this->input->post('private_notes'),
            'entered_this_year' => $this->input->post('entered_this_year'),
            'year_entered' => date('Y')
         );

        if (isset($_FILES['thumbnail']['name'])) {
            $toolToInsert['thumbnail_filename'] = $_FILES['thumbnail']['name'];
        }
        foreach($_POST as $pKey => $pVal) {
            if (substr($pKey,0,9) === 'category_') {
                error_log("Found a category: ".print_r($pVal,1)." for key of ".print_r($pKey,1));
                $post_category[] = substr($pKey,9);
            }
        }
        if (isset($post_category)) {
            $toolToInsert['category'] = implode(',',$post_category);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['active'])) {
            $toolToInsert['active'] = 1;
        }
        $this->load->model('Letme_model');
        $result = $this->Letme_model->insertTool('tool_db',$toolToInsert);
        echo "Result: \n";
        echo print_r($result,1);
    }

}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
```

Comment: There is way too much for us to go through here. You need to step through your code using `echo memory_get_usage(true); exit();` finding out exactly where the overload of memory comes from and then we can give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

one way to increase memory in php 5.x for uploading images is in your    `.htaccess`

just add this lines:

```
## I need more memory to upload large image
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 256M  ## or whatever you need
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, but on this account they don't allow access to .htaccess.

Comment: maybe spend a buck or 2 more for a decent hosting service? and what do you mean with no access to .htaccess? It's in your root directory, you should be able to control it!

Comment: It's not my choice, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I should clarify....they allow changes to .htaccess but not to memory_limit. Make it any higher than 120M and you'll get nothing but 500 errors. In fact, their help documentation pretty much spells that right out.

Truth be told, I've tried multiple times to convince my client that he should re-size the images *before* uploading them, but he doesn't want to do those extra steps. I'm hoping this experience is convincing him. Seriously, the images he's been trying lately are huge -- we're talking 3000 x 4000.